# Java changing the name of a button and incrementing count

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton, increment

So as of now I have created a 2D array of reference and added a button to each reference (or at least tried to).  Then I added in an action listener to each button.  When a button is pressed it is supposed to look at what button in the array was pressed.  If it is a "hit" increment hit and change the button from " ?" to " X".  If it is a "miss" increment miss and change the button from " ?" to "  ".  It still is not changing the buttons nor incrementing the counts.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Battleship extends JFrame{
    public int k;
    public int l;
    public int z;
     // Initialize counters.
    public int shipstartx = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    public int shipstarty = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    public int possitioning = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
    // Make hit and miss buttons.  Also make the normal button
    public Battleship(){
         ButtonListener listener1 = new ButtonListener();
         JButton Original[][] = new JButton[10][10];
        // Make the 10 by 10 grid.
        JPanel p1 = new JPanel();
        p1.setLayout(new GridLayout(10, 10));
        for (int i = 0; i <10; i++){
        for (int j = 0; j <10; j++){
            Original[i][j] = new JButton(" ?");
            p1.add(Original[i][j]);
            Original[i][j].addActionListener(listener1);
        }
        }
        // Add everything to a field so that the player can see it.
        add(new JTextField("Try to sink the battleship!"), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(p1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
        p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
        p2.add(new JTextField("Hits " + (k)));
        p2.add(new JTextField("Misses " + l));
        p2.add(new JTextField("Sinks " + z));
        add(p2, BorderLayout.WEST);
        // Now to make it so that the buttons actually do something.
    }
 public static void main (String[] args){
     Battleship frame = new Battleship();
     frame.setTitle("Battleship");
     frame.setSize(400, 300);
     frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
     frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     frame.setVisible(true);
 }
class ButtonListener implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        boolean hit = false;
        for (int a = 0; a < 10; a++){
        for (int b = 0; b < 10; b++){
          if (possitioning % 2 == 0){
           if (shipstartx+5 <= 10){
            if ((a == shipstartx || a == shipstartx+1 || a == shipstartx+2
                || a == shipstartx + 3 || a == shipstartx+4 || a == shipstartx+5)
                && b == shipstarty)
                hit = true;
            }
           else if ((a == shipstartx ||  a == shipstartx-1 || a == shipstartx-2
                   || a == shipstartx-3 || a == shipstartx-4 || a == shipstartx-5)
                   && b == shipstarty)
               hit = true;
          }
          else if (shipstarty+5 <= 10){
              if ((b == shipstarty || b == shipstarty+1 || b == shipstarty+2
                 || b == shipstarty+3 || b == shipstarty+4 || b == shipstarty+5)
                 && a == shipstartx)
               hit = true;
          }
          else if ((b == shipstarty || b == shipstarty-1 || b == shipstarty-2
                     || b == shipstarty-3 || b == shipstarty-4 || b == shipstarty-5)
                     && a == shipstartx)
              hit = true;
          else
              hit = false;
        }
        }
   if (hit == true){
       k=k+1;
    }
   else {
       l=l+1;
   }
   JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
   p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
   p2.add(new JTextField("Hits " + (k)));
   p2.add(new JTextField("Misses " + l));
   p2.add(new JTextField("Sinks " + z));
   add(p2, BorderLayout.WEST);
if (k == 3){
  z++;
  k = 0;
  l = 0;
 }
}
}
}
```

Comment: Rather the creating a new `JPanel` and text fields EACH time you click a button, why not maintain a reference to the text fields, as instance fields, and simply update there content (via `setText`)?

Comment: I also don't see anywhere you updating the button states.  It would also be easier to determine where the button is within the array (row/column) and simply perform a single calculation as opposed to looping so much, but that's just me...

Comment: I am not sure how you preform the calculation to get where the button is to compare to hit and miss...

Comment: What I might do is create a two dimensional array of 'int`s.  `0` been empty, non `0` values been representative of the each ship type you might like...You could then use a loop to find the index of the button and loop up the position in the "ship" array, or you could associate a `Point` object with the button, either through a `Map` or directly via [`get/setClientProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object))

Answer (score 2):

Instead of ...

```
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,1));
p2.add(new JTextField("Hits " + (k)));
p2.add(new JTextField("Misses " + l));
p2.add(new JTextField("Sinks " + z));
```

Each time you click a button, create three instance fields of type `JTextField` and uses those instead,

```
private JTextField hitsField;
private JTextField missiesField;
private JTextField sinksField;
```

Then in your constructor...

```
JPanel p2 = new JPanel();
p2.setLayout(new GridLayout(3, 1));

hitsField = new JTextField("Hits: 0", 10);
missiesField = new JTextField("Misses: 0", 10);
sinksField = new JTextField("Sinks: 0", 10);

p2.add(hitsField);
p2.add(missiesField);
p2.add(sinksField);
```

And in your `ActionListener` use something like...

```
hitsField.setText("Hits " + (k));
missiesField.setText("Misses " + (l));
sinksField.setText("Sinks " + (z));
```

You can also find the button which was clicked from the `ActionEvent`...

```
JButton btn = (JButton)e.getSource();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  However now that I know where the button was clicked from how do I match that up with the integers a and b to see if it is a hit or miss?  I tried doing if(a == btn) and (a == btn[a]) and even (btn[a] == a) but as you know you can't compare buttons to ints.

Comment: You got "another" question? - There are countless ways.  You could find the location of the button within the button array and use the x/y position for comparison, you could associate each button with a `Point` object (or array of `int`) via a `Map` or directly via the [`get/putClientProperty`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#putClientProperty(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object)) of the button